# File "abc1234.py", line 9 time.sleep(3) ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python

I am new to programming, I was trying to run this python program using terminal and getting the error: `File "abc1234.py", line 9 time.sleep(3)
IndentationError: expected an indented block
       ^`

```
import webbrowser
import time
time_total=3
time_count=0
print (" the current time is " +time.ctime())
while(time_count<time_total):
time.sleep(3)
webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=raabta+song+deepika")
time_count= time_count+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you formatted it based off your entry.
But your code should look like this:

```
import webbrowser
import time
time_total = 3
time_count = 0
print (" the current time is " + time.ctime())
while(time_count < time_total):
    time.sleep(3)
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=raabta+song+deepika")
    time_count = time_count + 1
```

You must indent all the code inside the while block. You must've not properly indented the `time.sleep(3)` on line 9. The interpreter was expecting at least one indented line following the colon of the **while loop**.

Comment: that code worked. however I am using the text editor "TextWrangler" and while using "while loop" do I have to manually add the spaces because after the : in the while loop it directly takes me to the next line without adding space like you have in your while loop

Comment: You can trying using the tab key perhaps? However, I would think that if it has python language support, somewhere in the preferences you would be able to enable auto-indent and define it to be 4 spaces. I'm not sure though, as I don't use TextWrangler personally.

Comment: that works .. Thank you @dor-ron

Comment: Sure thing glad to help